# When 1 of 2 rats die is there a suitable surrogate

Tags: psychology, rat

I had 2 older rats just over 3 years old. One has passed away. The other is still well and energetic. I do not want to commit to introducing another pair of rats for companionship at this time. It would mean another 3+ year commitment. I am offering him out of the cage time with me every day as well as daily time in the exercise ball. I am worried about the loss of companionship. Is anyone aware of a short term solution for companionship or a suitable surrogate partner?

Answer (score 1):

In their senior year I wouldn't introduce another rat, even though they are social there's a good chance he wont appreciate a new rat coming in.

Spend time with him daily, 3 years is a good long life for them, let him rest in peace for the time he has left :)

Comment: Rebecca, thank you for the advice. I contacted the animal rescue society this morning and they confirmed that Rune, the survivor, would be OK on  his own at his age. They also advised frequent interaction, out of cage time, and giving him additional objects and play things to stimulate and enrich his cage time. I also noticed that since he has been getting more extended periods of one on one time that he has started licking my hand. I suspect that may be pay back or his way of looking after me since it is now just the 2 of us.